# jQuery- Call function when textarea wraps to a new line?

Tags: jquery, textarea

I'd like to increase the height of a textarea when the text wraps to a new line, so it dynamically expands to whatever it needs to be. I don't want to use the onscroll event because I want the expansion to always be one step ahead of the scrolling, so the textarea never scrolls until it reaches a max height of x.

Anyway I could do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just decided to use this plugin: http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/textarea-expander/demo.html

Answer (score 2):

Numerous plug-ins [already exist](http://plugins.jquery.com/search/node/textarea+type%3Aproject_project+resizing+OR+growing+OR+expanding+-spelling+-pull+%22textarea%22) that do this. They probably don't do the maxheight deal, but you could add that in:

```
if ($(this).height() >= maxHeight) {
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know of any event that happens on wrap, you might be able to just use a keypress or change function and count the characters entered since the last wrap, and if it's over a given amount you can increase the size of the textarea.